# Create Knowledge article with channels in apex test code

Tags: apex, unit-test, knowledge

We have a use case where we expose knowledge articles to customer community users and I'm trying to write test code for that.

The problem I am having is that whenever I query for articles using system.runas(myUser) it does not return any results. This code is working perfectly when executed from the community (eg. the feature works) I am just failing to write unit tests for it.

Here is my test setup code

```
@testsetup
public static void createEvents() {
    List<Events__kav> newEvents = new List<Events__kav>();
    List<Events__DataCategorySelection> newCategorizations = new List<Events__DataCategorySelection>();
    for (Integer i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        Events__kav a = new Events__kav();
        a.Language = 'fr';
        a.Title = 'TestEvent' + i;
        a.UrlName = 'TestEvent' + i;
        a.Visible_on_App__c = true;
        a.Visible_on_Portal__c = true;
        newEvents.add(a);
    }
    insert newEvents;

    List<Events__kav> evts = [SELECT Id, KnowledgeArticleId FROM Events__kav WHERE Id IN :newEvents];
    List<Events__viewstat> evtsVS = new List<Events__viewstat>();
    for (Events__kav a : evts) {
        Events__DataCategorySelection dataCategory = new Events__DataCategorySelection();
        dataCategory.ParentId = a.Id;
        dataCategory.DataCategoryGroupName = 'Brand';
        dataCategory.DataCategoryName = 'Volkswagen';
        newCategorizations.add(dataCategory);
        KbManagement.PublishingService.publishArticle(a.KnowledgeArticleId, true); //PublishStatus = online
    }
    insert newCategorizations;
}
```

And this is the method that is not returning any results when called from the test class...

```
public static List<Events__kav> getAllEventDetails(String brandName, String language, Boolean visibleOnApp, Boolean visibleOnPortal) {
    String categoryQuery = 'SELECT 
      Id,Title,Summary,Full_Content__c,External_Link__c,
      External_Link_Label__c,Start_Date__c,End_Date__c,Location_Name__c,
      Location_Street__c,Location_Street_Number__c,Location_City__c,
      ArticleNumber FROM Events__kav 
         WHERE PublishStatus=\'online\' AND 
               Language = \'' + language + '\'';
    if (visibleOnApp && !visibleOnPortal) {
        categoryQuery = categoryQuery + ' AND Visible_On_App__c = ' + visibleOnApp;
    } else if (!visibleOnApp && visibleOnPortal) {
        categoryQuery = categoryQuery + ' AND Visible_On_Portal__c = ' + visibleOnPortal;
    } else { //if above clauses fail then both app and portal have the same value.
        categoryQuery = categoryQuery + ' AND Visible_On_App__c = ' + visibleOnApp + ' AND Visible_On_Portal__c = ' + visibleOnPortal;
    }
    categoryQuery = categoryQuery + ' AND Start_date__c >= THIS_MONTH WITH DATA CATEGORY Brand__c BELOW ' + brandName + '__c';
    //categoryQuery = categoryQuery + ' ORDER BY Start_Date__c ASC';
    List<Events__kav> events = (List<Events__kav>) Database.query(categoryQuery);
    return events;
}
```

Comment: Have you checked what values are being passed to `getAllEventDetails()` through test class?